# Convert tapply output to data frame in R

Tags: r

I have some output from a tapply call that looks like

```
1        2       4
678.2    19.3    716.2
```

and I want to make it into a data frame that looks like

```
     key    value
1    1      678.2
2    2      19.3
3    4      716.2
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Provide dput() from that object. I can see why the question was downvoted but you can edit it to clarify the situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some example code would be nice, to see exactly what you're doing. To answer your question narrowly, if `x` is the result of your `tapply`, then

```
data.frame(key=names(x), value=x)
```

More broadly, see `?by` and `?aggregate`, and also package `plyr` for more general data-wrangling needs.

Comment: that is incorrect. that gives the key 4 having an index of 4, not 3

Comment: @CodeGuy: I don't know what you mean, but I'm assuming you did `as.numeric(key)` and saw that 4 was mapped to 3. If you don't want `key` to be a factor, do `key=as.numeric(names(x))`.

Comment: hm. nope, didn't do as.numeric. what I mean is, from my question above, you can see that the index 3 has a key of 4 and a value of 716.2

Comment: in addition, I have a bunch of levels. how do I get rid of levels, which are messing up the plotting

Comment: @CodeGuy When I run Hong Ooi's code I get output in exactly the form you say you want. If you aren't, there's likely something else going on that you haven't told us.

Comment: How can I use this to coerce by() output to a data frame?

Answer (score 14):

If you replace `tapply` with aggregate it will automatically come out as a data.frame.

```
aggregate( value ~ key, FUN = mean )
```

where value and key correspond to the `tapply` call

```
tapply( value, key, mean )
```